# Meteor Up (mup) on EC2 Deployment Different from Local App

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, meteor, meteor-up

On localhost, the app works just fine.

On EC2, the app runs behind nginx. It loads into the browser, but nothing shows up. The browser console displays an Error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Package["service-configuration"].ServiceConfiguration')
```

I have no idea how to tackle this problem. Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**

1. NGINX is not the problem. The same behavior if I access meteor server directly.
2. Running "meteor add service-configuration" does fix the above mentioned error, but the absence of the error does not fix the observed behavior, that the app does not render on EC2 whereas it does render when started on localhost. (The error message was the only visible difference between EC2 and localhost. So I suspected that would be the cause. Now that hypothesis must be wrong.) So the problem still persists.

**Problem Solved. The Lesson:**

Meteor has a debug mode and a production mode. The two may behave differently. On localhost, meteor runs in debug mode per default. On deploy to meteor.com or per mup, the default is production mode. To run meteor in production mode on localhost, run `meteor --production`.

Comment: It looks like you haven't got your packages installed on the server. Try running `mrt install` from your project root and restart your app to see if that resolves the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to access the `service-configuration` configs on your browser.

These are not available client side. This also affects your localhost app but it doesn't break your app (doesn't give you a blank page) because meteor is in debug mode.

In debug mode Meteor files are not concatenated so an error like this would go unnoticed, even if it is thrown on your js console. In production mode the error would halt the rest of your script (since everything is concatenated into a single file)

You need to ensure the code that is doing this only runs on the server side. In general it's not a good idea to have access to the service configuration data on the client side.

Comment: Hm. I am still very confused. I ran **meteor add service-configuration** and the error message goes away. Still the app does not render. and why is the behavior different on localhost and on ec2?

Comment: I think your comment is very helpful. But it poses so many questions. I didn't even know meteor has a debug mode. Where is this documented? Then: I need to be able to sign up client side. Therefore I am setting `Accounts.config({forbidClientAccountCreation: false})`. Is this causing service-configuration to be required? Why don't I have the error when app is run on localhost?

Comment: You will also be seeing this error on your local host. You can use production mode on your local machine by running `meteor --production`, instead of `meteor`. I think setting `Accounts.config` is fine. I'm not too sure what is causing it. If you run on localhost in  normal `meteor` mode you will see the error thrown in your console and find what is causing it from there. Its not documented well but if you run `meteor run help` its listed there as production mode

Comment: There's very little difference between production and debug mode. Mainly files are concatenated into a single one and mified (css and js). This error just stops the script running, e.g like `throw "someerror"; console.log("this wont run")`. When your files are minified the code later on wont run like it would when the files are split up

Comment: Thanks! Now everything makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Arunoda and crew are adding a `buildOptions.debug` setting to the next version of MUP, which should allow you to deploy via MUP and have it act like it's running on `localhost`. See [Arunoda's answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30135807/2669596) and (at least for now) [documentation for the development version of MUP](https://goo.gl/rJn99A).