# Can I use Velocity with Meteor Up?

Tags: meteor, meteor-up, meteor-velocity

I recently started using [Velocity](http://velocity.meteor.com/) with Meteor and really like having the HTML reporter as I go. It would be great if the rest of my team could see the testing status on our dev and testing servers, which are deployed on AWS EC2 via [Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up).

Unfortunately, Velocity relies on Meteor running in debug mode (what you get with `meteor` or `meteor run` locally), and turns off for production deployments (running the Node app that you get from `meteor build`). Meteor Up (as well as most PaaS deployment solutions) use `meteor build` in the deployment pipeline, so Velocity doesn't run when I deploy via `mup`. I've tried setting environment variables like `NODE_ENV="development"` and `NODE_OPTIONS="--debug"` but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to get Meteor Up to deploy my app in debug mode?

Comment: It's possible to run `meteor build foo --debug`, but if there's a way to do this without forking Meteor Up then I'd rather do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Arunoda here from Mup

We are working on the next version of Mup and it has a way to enable the debug flag when deploying.

See: https://goo.gl/rJn99A

> This version of mup uses Docker and it's much more stable than the current version. (We used it to deploy all our app)

Comment: Glad to hear it! This should be helpful not only for Velocity but also for other dev tools like msavin's Meteor Toys. There are definitely some use cases for building with --debug.

Comment: The link is dead. It can be found at: https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up/blob/master/README.md#build-options

If that breaks, the project is https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up

Answer (score 1):

this is not currently supported in Velocity. The way you mentioned is the only way with the --debug flag. Perhaps you can create a PR for MUP to allow this option

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Looks like MUP is adding a `--debug` option, which should do the trick. 
Velocity is a great tool and keeps getting better; thanks for your support there and with the [Meteor Test Manual](http://www.meteortesting.com/). Looking forward to seeing what else [Xolvio](http://xolv.io) has in store with [Simian](http://simian.io/) and beyond.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words!